# Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array of objects, an example of a few of them being

```
[
    {
        "lang_code":        "eng",
        "site_language":    "1",
        "name":         "English"
    },
    {
        "lang_code":        "afr",
        "site_language":    "1",
        "name":         "Afrikaans"
    },
    {
        "lang_code":        "ale",
        "site_language":    "0",
        "name":         "Aleut"
   },
]
```

I want to be able to search the whole array for a specific `lang_code`, let's say I use `eng`. I want to search the whole array for `eng`. If it's there, I want it to return `English`, if not, I want it to return `invalid`. Any ideas on this?

Comment: `for` loop, `filter()`/`map()` combo ... plenty of options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic and more flexible version of the findById function above:

```
// array = [{key:value},{key:value}]
function objectFindByKey(array, key, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i][key] === value) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var array = your array;
var result_obj = objectFindByKey(array, 'lang_code', 'eng');
```

[Click here for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viranijigs/xq6L2v6z/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function findLang(arr, code) {
  var filtered = arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.lang_code === code;
  });

  // filter returns an array of objects that match the criteria
  // if the array is not empty return the language,
  // otherwise return 'invalid'
  return filtered.length > 0 ? filtered[0].name : 'invalid';
}

findLang(arr, 'eng'); // English
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/o23mvxcy/1/)

If you wanted to add [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) into the mix instead of using that ternary operation (but which would most likely be slower and doesn't really provide any additional benefit):

```
function findLang(arr, code) {
  return arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.lang_code === code;
  }).map(function (el) {
    return el.name;
  })[0] || 'invalid';
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/o23mvxcy/3/)

Answer (score 1):

How about a `for` loop.  Something like:

```
function find_lang(input_arr, lang_code) {
   for(var i = 0; i < input_arr.length; i++) {
      var o = input_arr[i];
      if( o.lang_code === lang_code ) {
         return o.name;
      }
   }

   return "invalid";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Underscore.js has some useful helpers for this kind of thing: http://underscorejs.org/

E.g Find:

> Looks through each value in the list, returning the first one that
>   passes a truth test (predicate), or undefined if no value passes the
>   test. The function returns as soon as it finds an acceptable element,
>   and doesn't traverse the entire list.

```
var even = _.find([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; });
    => 2
```

Where:

> Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the
>   values that contain all of the key-value pairs listed in properties.

```
_.where(listOfPlays, {author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611});
=> [{title: "Cymbeline", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611},
    {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
// configure your parameters
function checkArr(){
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        if (x[i].lang_code == "eng")
            return "English";
    }
    return "invalid";
}

var x = [
{
    "lang_code":        "eng",
    "site_language":    "1",
    "name":         "English"
},
{
    "lang_code":        "afr",
    "site_language":    "1",
    "name":         "Afrikaans"
},
{
    "lang_code":        "ale",
    "site_language":    "0",
    "name":         "Aleut"
}
];
```